# redirect issue after the registration

Tags: php, laravel, routes

UserController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    
    function create(Request $request) {

        // Validate the request

        $request->validate([

            'name'      => 'required',
            'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password'  => 'required|min:5|max:30',
            'cpassword' => 'required|min:5|max:30|same:password'
        ]);

        $user = new User();

        $user->name     = $request->name;
        $user->email    = $request->email;
        $user->password = \Hash::make($request->password);

        $save = $user->save();

        if( $save ) {
            
            //return redirect()->back->with('success', 'you are register successfully');
            return redirect()->route('user.create')->with('success', 'you are register successfully');
        }

            else {

                return redirect()->back->with('fail', 'something went wrong, failed to register');
            }

    }
}
```

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::prefix('user')->name('user.')->group( function() {

    Route::middleware(['guest'])->group( function () {

        Route::view('/login','dashboard.user.login')->name('login');
        Route::view('/register', 'dashboard.user.register')->name('register');
        Route::post('/create',[UserController::class,'create'])->name('create');
    });

    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group( function () {

        Route::view('/home', 'dashboard.user.home')->name('home');
    });
});
```

[image]

I research a lot on Google and try different way but my problem is not solved.  I have only an issue with redirect and the data is submitted successfully in the database and give me the following error when the form is submitted as shown in the picture.

If I use `return redirect()->back->with('', '');`, then it give me this error as shown in image:

[image]

Comment: "back" is a function so use redirect()->back()

Comment: Great worked now, the problem is with me Monkey see, monkey do

Comment: `redirect()->route('user.create')...` - this redirects with GET back to your create route.  But you have no GET create route, only POST: `Route::post('/create' ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first unknown route problem :

you can try this :

```
Route::post('/user/create',[UserController::class,'create'])->name('create');
```

instead of :

```
Route::post('/create',[UserController::class,'create'])->name('create');
```

In my opinion, if the form is not processed and gets an error, then once on the next page, there is no point in going over an error

Answer (score 2):

I think "the GET method is not supported.." this issue comes from **form submission**. Please recheck the html form method and if it is set to method="get" then update it to method="post". If there is still issue remains, please comment here.

Comment: The problem has been solved with this first comment that is "back" is a function so use redirect()->back() – Kashan Baig but there is not tickmark sign that I marked the problem solved

Comment: Understood. But how can you solve the issue of "The GET method is not supported for this route". I am just wondering.